# Error Configuring Reporting Services in Team Foundation Server 2010 post install

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are configuring SQL Server Reporting Services on an existing installation of TFS 2010 RTM.

After configuring the Warehouse, Analysis Services and Reports tab in the TFS Administration Console, I get the following error: "Failed to add BUILTIN\Administrators account to the TfsWarehouseDataReader role on the Tfs_Warehouse relational database."

However, when I open SQL Server Management Studio and look at the users for the Tfs_Warehouse database, BUILTIN\Administrators does exist as a user and is in the TfsWarehouseDataReader Role.

An empty Tfs_Warehouse database is created but nothing else happens.

Please help.

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: You should ask this on ServerFault, not StackOverflow

Comment: Ok. It would be nice if one could just move the question.

Comment: @Dave: click on "Edit", then click Ctrl-A to select all, and go to the other site and paste in your question....

Comment: @RyanHennig - TFS questions have been traditionally answered here at StackO-- even these kind.

Comment: @marc_s - if this does need to go to ServerFault, couldn't you do that as a mod?  I still believe it belongs here, though.

Comment: Does the account you're logged in and running the config as have sysadmin permissions to both the SSAS and OLTP databases?